# Pass the same variables to itself in an IntentService when it restarts itself

Tags: android, intentservice

I have an IntentService that needs to be restarted wenn it is destroyed. 
Originaly I get all the variables from an Intent in `protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {...}`
The variables are change during the runtime of the service. Once I close (destroy) the App, the service stops, but I want it to contiune running until I tell it to stop.
To restart the IntentService I call:

```
return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
```

but the values of the variables are reset to the Original value. But I need the values from the IntentService before it restarted.

**So my question is:**
Is there anyway to change the intent that is passed to the IntentService when `return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;` is called?
Or is there anyother way to save the variables so that the variables can be reused in the restarted IntentService?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use preference in this place.
while you sending data using intent at that time store that data in preference.

this data will store in phone ram . so while you update or uninstall that app till that time it will store. so you no need to face this probable.

call preference while you need that data.

example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm